# Uninstalls from ChromeOS increased in my extension. Have ChromeOS any browser API difference from other OS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the extension New Tab Studio https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-studio-countdown/epngggilgnflanfabeldfpbgponcgpgl

Several days ago uninstalls from ChromeOS became so big (other OS - as usual).
I wanna try to install ChromeOS on VirtualBox and test my extension, but it's not a very easy task, maybe it's easier to buy Chromebook.

But first of all, 
**Can my extension has specific bug only for ChromeOS?**

*Also, I have anonymous messages from google forms, that app crashes (on the background button click), but I cannot reproduce any bugs on Mac OS or Windows.*

Comment: Chrome shows a confirmation periodically about the start page replacement. ChromeOS might be doing it more frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced it on Linux (i think that the cores of ChromeOS browser and Linux are the same)

So, the case was that I had the image with path `/all.jpeg`, but was requesting `/All.jpeg`. MacOS and Windows was fine with this typo, they even show me the image.

But Linux (and I guess ChromeOS) crashed the extension. And the crash was observed only in the extension installed from Chrome Web Store (my local production build just didn't show the image, but worked fine)